# Where does it say that as long as someone believes in there being only one God he/she will go to paradise eventually?

Tags: hadith

I forgot if it was a Hadith or something else. But it said that as long someone believed in monotheism and didn't have any beliefs that contradicted Quran then one day eventually they will enter heaven/paradise.

Again this is not ideal. This is not saying what should be done, but rather what is the minimum.

Comment: One who has not done Kufr will (eventually) enter paradise. This follows from [4:116](https://quran.com/4/116) and there are ahadith to the effect e.g. [this](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/178) and [this](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/15).

Comment: what if a person isn't a muslim as in follows Quran, but has no opinion on Islam being right or wrong and doesn't disagree with Quran. Just believes there is a God and one God.

Comment: And how is this person a non-muslim? If he believes in the Quran he believes in Allah and the Prophet and all the essential aqeedah. A non-muslim is a kafir and will be in hell forever there are a multitude of verses on that e.g. [33:64-66](https://quran.com/33/64-66)

Comment: a person who only believes in there being only one God, but has no opinion on anything else.

Comment: Such a person has committed Kufr as he has not believed in Allah, His Messengers, His Books etc. and follows a religion other than Islam [48:13](http://quran.com/48/13) , [3:85](https://quran.com/3/85)

Comment: but he hasn't disbelieved in them either, except Allah. For example parents/ancestors of prophet Muhammad PBUH, I remember reading one of the ancestors saying that idols are not 'right' dont know what is but they aren't. Rejecting idols but only believing that there is one God.

Answer (score -2):

In addition from the comment section, Allah states inside the Qur'an that the concept of Heaven is to accept Islam after being given a clear explanation. This is based on the word of Him from **surah al-Baqarah**, verses 111 and 112. In **verse 111**, Allah declares that Jews and Christians claim that no one can enter Heaven unless they are Jews and Christians. Allah states that it is only their assumption. In fact, He challenges them to come up with arguments, if they believe they are on the right path.

In **verse 112**, God also explains who actually goes into heaven, those who "as-la-ma" (surrender) themselves to Him.

From this understanding, it is clear that those who will be going to the Heaven/paradise is those who;

1. Explanation of knowledge in the form on strong argument
2. After the strong explanation, the person accept and surrender to Him.

Those who reject these two factor are then being called non-believer *(kafir)*. However, if there is no direct explanation, or there is an explanation but is not strong, or gives a wrong explanation, or the Muslims themselves display a false character in the meaning of Islam, then the rejection cannot be considered as non-believer *(kafir).*

Wallahualam.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question: if person believes in God but doesn't have any opinions on anything else including Islam. what happens then? I remember reading that eventually they go to heaven.

Comment: I remember listening to one of my Ustad's tazkirah (talk), that if the person is an Islam, and even he has only an "atom" big of iman in himself, then he will be going to Heaven eventually. This is to state that, as long as the person is an Islam, Allah will reward him with Heaven

Comment: That is well known and accepted. So while it's true, it doesn't answer the question.